# Not able to set a scroll to an id when clicking on an anchor with nextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, anchor, gsap, scrollto

I can't achieve doing this simple thing.
Actually, I do with this

```
<Link id="membre" href={`/membres/${membres.slug}#membre-anchor`}
```

but It brings me to the bottom of the block.

I try a lot of option, but nothing Like I wanted to : When I click on a member's name the window automatically scroll to the part of the page where the profile is.

Here are my 2 components code :

member/[slug].js

```
import { fetchAPI } from "../../lib/api";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import { Container, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import Membre from "../../components/membre";


export default function Member({ membre, membres, categories, quote, types }) {

  return (
    <>
      <Container className="member-container">
        <Row className="row-quote">
          <p className="quote">
            {quote.text}
          </p>
          <div className="member-section">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <path
              fill="none"
              stroke="#eb1615"
              strokeMiterlimit={10}
              d="M5.55-.15l6.95 10L5.19 20"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
        </Row>
       
       
        <Row className="col-membre"  >
          <Col className="img-membre">
            <img id="membre-anchor" src={membre.img.url}
              width="200" />
          </Col>
          <Col className="text-membre">
            <p className="name" >
              {membre.name}
            </p>
            <p className="fonction">
              {membre.fonctions}
            </p>
            <div>
              <ReactMarkdown source={membre.bio} />
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Membre types={types} />
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}


export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const membres = await fetchAPI("/membres")

  return {
    paths: membres.filter(membre => membre.slug).map((membre) => ({
      params: {
        slug: membre.slug
      },
    })),
    fallback: 'blocking',
  }
}


export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const membre = (await fetchAPI(`/membres?slug=${params.slug}`))[0]
  const [membres, categories, quote, types] = await Promise.all([
    fetchAPI("/membres"),
    fetchAPI("/categories"),
    fetchAPI("/quote"),
    fetchAPI("/types"),
  ])
  return {
    props: { membre, membres, categories, quote, types },
    revalidate: 1,
  }
}
```

Member.js

```
import { Col } from "react-bootstrap"
import Link from "next/link"; 


const Membre = ({ types }) => {
   
    return (
        <>
            <Col id="membre-types">
                {types.map((type) => (
                    <div key={type.id} className="type">
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>{type.membreType}</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        {type.membres.map((membres) => (
                                            <div key={membres.id}>
                                                <Link id="membre" href {`/membres/${membres.slug}#membre-anchor`}
                                                ariaLabel="Scroll to #membre-anchor"
                                                > 
                                                    <a
                                                    >
                                                        {membres.name}
                                                    </a>
                                                </Link>
                                            </div>
                                        ))}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </Col>
        </>
    )
}

export default Membre
```

I tried to add a gsap fonction onClick like this :

```
const handleOnClick = () => {
gsap.to(window, {
duration: 1,
scrollTo: '#membre-anchor'
})
}
```

But I guess I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. Clicking on the `membre` link loads that member's data and correctly scrolls down to the anchored element. It may be the case that you're not seeing the scroll happening because the page is already positioned with the `Link` in the viewport, since the links come right after it.

Comment: It actually works almost fine like this, but I still one problem, I would like to link to the top of the block instead of the bottom